# warning: Insecure world writable dir when I run a ruby or gem command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, osx-snow-leopard

Not sure why I'm getting this, but I just installed RVM, the new Ruby 1.9, and reinstalled a bunch of gems, and I get this

/Users/johnsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777

Everything still runs otherwise, but I was wondering if there was a way I could get rid of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ warning Insecure world writable dir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the warning "Insecure world writable dir /home/chance " in PATH, mode 040777 for rails and gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380671/getting-the-warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-home-chance-in-path-mode-04)

Comment: Duplicate of: [warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-local-bin-in-path-mode-040777)

Comment: @kenorb Eh.. this question was asked first

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Just `chmod go-w /opt/local/bin` at a shell prompt (depending on permissions you may need to `sudo` to do that).

Comment: Yes! you are a genius! And that concludes my successful installation of RVM, ruby 1.9, and the 64-bit challenge :D

Comment: @ming, any program running on your machine can put anything it wants in `/opt/local/bin` (so in particular any executable "shadowing" any system one and other such trojans) without so much as a by-your-leave: how is that **not** insecure?!

Comment: Are you saying that this answer is a terrible idea and using it will open up a huge security hole in my system?

Comment: `chmod: /opt/local/bin: No such file or directory`

Comment: `chmod go-w /usr/local/bin` in OSX

Comment: thanks, this helped me sort out another problem related to the same issue

Answer (score 11):

To clarify, whatever path returns after it says insecure world writeable, is what you use.

So instead of: chmod go-w /opt/local/bin you would replace /opt/local/bin with whatever your path is.

Answer (score 3):

Find your gem path so we can edit the bundler gem. Execute the following in your shell:

```
$ ruby -r rubygems -e "p Gem.path"
```

Navigate to your gem path and cd into the version of bundler currently being used. Now navigate to lib -> bundler and open runtime.rb in your favorite text editor. Add “$VERBOSE = nil” to line 2.

```
require "digest/sha1" 
$VERBOSE = nil 
module Bundler   
class Runtime < Environment
    include SharedHelpers

    def setup(*groups)
      # Has to happen first
      clean_load_path
```

...

Comment: This silences all output including output from rake tasks. Not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (like mine), the stack goes deeper than `opt/local/bin`. In that case, use

```
sudo chmod go-w opt/local/*/bin usr/local/*/bin opt/local/bin usr/local/bin
```

In any case, the error prompts where the insecure world is.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment does not allow you to fix this error properly (i.e. ruby lives on a network share or some such), see [this answer for a way to suppress the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868701/830254).