# Error installing mysql gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I am using linux machine. I successfully installed ruby and create a simple application with sqlite database. It's also works well. Now i try to create an application with mysql, when i install mysql gem it shows following error.

```
[bathakarai@Project1-CO Rails]$ gem install mysql
/home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/bathakarai in PATH, mode 040777
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:12: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/bathakarai in PATH, mode 040777
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
/home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link0'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in have_func'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:45:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Please help me where the problem is

Comment: Do you have mysql,mysql-dev installed?

Comment: I already have mysql in my machine but not mysql gem

Comment: Have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir

I think this will resolve your issue

Comment: No my problem is not solved. got the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of unavailability of some of development dependencies in local.

install the following

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-dev
```

then install the **mysql** gem with

```
gem install mysql
```

Comment: I used "yum install mysql-dev" . it shows "No package mysql-dev available." message. (I am using linux machine)

Comment: Which linux you are using? Ubuntu or any thing else?

Comment: can you try this `sudo yum -y install gcc mysql-devel` and then `gem install mysql`.

Answer (score 8):

Just try this. Hope it will works for you

Firstly install libmysql-ruby with

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby
```

Then install  libmysqlclient-dev with

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

After the above completed Install mysql with

```
sudo gem install mysql
```

Comment: IN linux environemnt i tired "yum install libmysql-ruby" , it shows "No package libmysql available." message

Comment: Don't you tried this `sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby`. It's for Linux environment

Comment: You don't have to install libmysql-ruby. I tried this with Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Answer (score 1):

**install some mysql2 dependency**

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

**insert into your GemFile**

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

**then bundle install**

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/mysql in PATH, mode 040777

The solution is a simple one-liner I forget every damn time.

```
sudo chmod o+w /usr/local/mysql/bin
```

[Click Here for more detail](http://www.headhole.org/2010/05/18/insecure-world-writable-dir/)

Answer (score -1):

Please type:

```
gem install mysql2 --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?