# Errors in starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a rails site with the ***rails new {project_name} -d mysql***

and then cd to the project_name and ran the **rails server** command but got the error below, what could be the problem? Anyone knows? do i have to change the mode 040777? if yes, how? thanks

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/henryjoseph/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: I tried that, I got this : "Could not locate Gemfile" ...

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ur_dir
```

then you have to connect your mysql database to your project.
for this you see the config/database.yml file where you have to add this

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: your_database_name
  pool: 5
  username: your_db_username
  password: ur_db_password
  host: localhost
```

then rails s