# Can't get CocoaPods working

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods, xcode6, osx-yosemite-beta

I installed CocoaPods and it says `Successfully installed cocoapods-0.33.1`, but whatever I would try to do with `pod` command, like `pod install`, I get the following console output:

```
Max$ pod install
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal.x86_64-darwin14-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/bin/pod:32:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I am using Mac OS 10.10 (Yosemite beta version) and Xcode 6.0 beta2, but I think back when I used Mavericks and Xcode 5.1.1 I had the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.

## Short answer:

I had to install ruby 2.1.2, then reinstall cocoapods and everything worked.

## Long answer:

1. Resolve all warnings from `brew doctor`;

   - remove unused libraries;
   - remove MacPorts;
   - resolve additional warnings which I already do not remember;
   - I might even reinstalled brew.
2. Install `rvm`;
3. Install & use ruby 2.1.2 using rvm;

   - `rvm requirements` complains about many missing packages, install them;
   - among them, there is gcc46, which I was unable to install. After Xcode 4.2 or something, command line tools come without gcc. So if `rvm requirements` does not find one, it suggests gcc46. But the point is, installing **`brew install apple-gcc42`** solves the problem. `rvm requirements` stops complaining and you can install ruby 2.1.2:
   - `rvm install 2.1.2`;
   - `rvm use 2.1.2`;
4. Install cocoapods, as suggested in @Varsha Vijayvargiya's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011418/cant-get-cocoapods-working/25013276#25013276).

I might forgot something, so if you have any questions - ask. Here are some links which helped me:

- [update mac osx to 10.10 and pod cannot work](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2219);
- [Installing Ruby 2.0.0 with RVM and Homebrew on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion);
- [Homebrew GCC won't install on OS X 10.10 Yosemite with Xcode 6](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29845);
- [Installing gcc on Mavericks](https://coderwall.com/p/lqpp8w).

Answer (score 3):

-- Open Xcode 6

-- Open Preferences

-- click on Locations tab

-- Change the Command Line Tools version to Xcode 6.0

-- Uninstall cocoapods

```
    $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

-- Install xcodeproj

```
     $ sudo gem install xcodeproj
```

-- Install cocoapods

```
     $ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

-- Run pod.

Comment: This worked for me but only after I updated ruby using this tutorial: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.9-mavericks

Answer (score 3):

You most probably missed a step, but it's not your fault.

1. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. **`pod setup`** <–- this is not specified by the doc even though it's **vital**
3. `pod install`

Comment: This seemed to help me in 2022 with Xcode 13.2 and iOS 15. You gotta be kidding me.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2219

Or check that if you have multi ruby versions in your system:`rbenv versions`, and try `rbenv global 1.9.x` to change your ruby version for installing.

Answer (score 1):

First warning says that you've insecure permissions for your bin directory:

local:Documents liuxiaojun$ gem update --system
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.4.3
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-2.4.3
Installing RubyGems 2.4.3
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/gauntlet_rubygems.rb

==========
brew install ruby 
OK

Answer (score 0):

First warning says that you've insecure permissions for your bin directory:

```
warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
```

See: [warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir)

You can fix it via (you need root credentials):

```
sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin
```

The error `'require': cannot load such file` indicates that you some missing or broken gem package. You can probably fix it by re-installing cocoapods:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods # Follow by sudo if necessary
gem install cocoapods --verbose # Follow by sudo if necessary
```

And make sure that your xcodeproj is present:

```
gem install xcodeproj --verbose # Follow by sudo if necessary
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already solved my problem. See the accepted answer.

Comment: Great. No worries, it'll be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

my experience: I had the same error after upgrading to Yosemite, I just did a "gem update" and it worked.