# Getting the warning “Insecure world writable dir ...” after upgrade PostgreSQL

Tags: macos, postgresql, permissions, homebrew

After upgrade from PostgreSQL 9.3.5 to 9.4.0 I'll cleaned previous version via

```
brew cleanup postgresql
```

but getting error, when want to start working with new version of PostgreSQL:

```
relrin at MacBook-Relrin in ~ exited 127 
=> psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Ok, try restart postgre:

```
relrin at MacBook-Relrin in ~ 
=> lunchy stop postgre
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/lunchy-0.8.0/lib/lunchy.rb:138: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Could not find specified service
stopped homebrew.mxcl.postgresql
```

How can I fix this last issue, that I could work with the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-local-bin-in-path-mode-040777)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Stopping postgre process and `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` didn't help - already tryed

Comment: The problem in your error message is `Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777`; the directory permissions to fix are the 777 permissions on `/usr`.  The technique required is described in the the duplicate question, though there it applied to `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr`.  You might need to check other places for the error too — that is, fixing `/usr` may reveal a problem in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local` or `/usr/local/bin` afterwards.  Many commands report just the first error, not all possible errors. Note that the related questions include one for `/usr/local`.