# NameError: uninitialized constant ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I am following the tutorial on Lynda on Ruby on rails 4.

I have having multiple issues:

1. I am getting the security issue which I don't know how to remove it
2. I keep getting `NameError` when I am creating anything new.

I am stuck, any help would much appreciated

---

```
mikf$ rails c

/Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

/Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/run.rb:68: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

/Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

/Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777


Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)

irb(main):001:0> **subject =Subject.new**
NameError: uninitialized constant Subject
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mikf/Documents/simple_cms/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/mikf/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: Do you define the `Subject` class?

Comment: I just got it to work, didn't have model set up

Comment: You can find a solution for the security warnings here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-local-bin-in-path-mode-040777