# I am using Deepin linux 15.4.1. I want to install Ruby language for what, i want to execute Sass/SCSS. but Now I tried to do this as root user:

Tags: ruby, linux, sass

```
gem install sass
```

But, I get this error.

```
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.10.2.gem (100%)
```

Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.2
Fetching: ffi-1.9.18.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:76: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171018-24304-17ddhmp.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out

what's wrong here? i installed Ruby stable release Ruby 2.4.2  [Ruby stable release Ruby 2.4.2](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of errors are usually system compiler errors where your system might not have the correct core c libraries installed.   Have a look at this thread for ideas on how you might fix this.

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2357

How is Ruby installed?  RVM, RBENV, Type this in terminal and give us outputs:

```
which ruby
ruby -v
```

Also did you try running `sudo gem install sass`  ?

UPDATE:  You may need root access to where the gem is trying to install. See [warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-local-bin-in-path-mode-040777#3952325)

Also can you post output of  `echo $PATH` ?
and also `ruby -v` and `which ruby`   Hard to see what's going on without that.

I would also recommend you use RVM to install ruby.  Not sure if you your linux version comes with pre-installed ruby version, but you can install other Ruby versions with RVM.

Comment: yes, I used  `sudo gem install sass` 
also that displayed error in common above error.

Comment: the problem does resolved. my system might not have correct c libraries installed. so, after installed that, fix that issue. Thank you!

Comment: @snishalaka if this helped, feel free to upvote answer (karma) thanks.