# I got error when install Homebrew on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, curl

I ran bellow command according to the instruction on the site. But I got this error.

site : https://brew.sh/

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
-bash: $: command not found
```

I investigated to enable SSL on curl, but I couldn't find the resolution on my environment. So I accessed https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install by browser and downloaded to local and ran it. But I got this error.

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/Users/tadashingo/Documents/install)"
-bash: /Users/tadashingo/Documents/install: Permission denied
```

I tried this workaround, but I still got the error. 
[warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-local-bin-in-path-mode-040777)

Could you please guide me to install Homebrew on my environment?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

I changed the name from "install" to "install.rb2", go to the directory and ran it.

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby install.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning about insecure directory `/usr/local/bin` can be solved by running

```
sudo chown o-w /usr/local/bin
```

You get the error about permission denied running `install` because you invoke it the wrong way.

Run it as:

```
$ ruby /Users/tadashingo/Documents/install
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

After a recent pull request, this is the new installation command for HomeBrew.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSLhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```