# warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/fee/Documents/flutter/bin in PATH, mode 040707

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods, release-builds

im trying to build my apk for ios using flutter but the Cocoapods throw an error which is

```
warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/fee/Documents/flutter/bin in PATH, mode
040707
```

i look in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-local-bin-in-path-mode-040777)

but i dont know how to apply in my project, can anyone help me