# Unable to run npx react-native init

Tags: react-native

I keep getting this error:

```
✖ Installing Bundler
error /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/rbconfig.rb:230: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users(my path here)/ in PATH, mode 040777

✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
    at createFromTemplate
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func]
```

Ive spent too long on this, someone please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-local-bin-in-path-mode-040777)

Comment: Thanks @Julia I have already had a look at that before creating this post. Unfortunately did not help

Comment: “It did not help” Why? What was the exact command you used? Which error(s) did you get (if any)? Please [edit] your question to add this information.