# Installed Ruby on Rails but when I try to run Rails Sever it doesn't load WEBrick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I installed Ruby on Rails on my mac today along with Gems and MYsql. I'm trying to follow the lynda.com tutorial and I've run into a brick wall. When I try to run the rails server it doesnt load WEBrick for some reason. This is the error I get:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/nutanpatel/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Any ideas on what I could do? Please help - I'm stuck!

I did rails -v and I'm on 3.0.5:

```
rails -v
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Rails 3.0.5
```

BTW: I tried to go and do this `sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin` but this did not resolve anything.
Reason I did this was because of: [warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir)

Comment: Try one or all of these: http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512362/rails-server-fails-to-start-with-mysql2-using-rvm-ruby-1-9-2-p0-on-osx-10-6-5 and http://pinoytech.org/question/5360152/setting-up-mysql-with-the-latest-version-of-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly urge you to use rvm to install ruby and try again:

- http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

There are a number of issues with the default ruby that ships with OS X. When you install RVM, you can easily get a clean installation of ruby.

Make sure to read the install instructions carefully, especially the last bit about inserting a line into your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872680/warning-while-installing-the-rails-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `warning: Insecure world writable dir` error, that's just a warning from Bundler and has nothing to do with the error that is keeping Rails from starting.

That error is due to the Mysql2 gem not loading properly. I had the same problem. Basically you need the mysql source files for the gem to compile properly. I solved it by installing Homebrew, then installing mysql with Homebrew, then running `Bundle install` again.

Try this:

1. install [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation)
2. install mysql with hombrew: `brew install mysql` in a terminal
3. delete the `Gemfile.lock` file inside your Rails app
4. run 'bundle install` again
5. try starting Rails with this command: `bundle exec rails server`

I know I'm a little late to this party, but I'm hoping this might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

Comment: I'm  kind of lost on what you mean by set Gemfile. I did run bundle install and this is what it said: 

"Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed."

I tried to run rails server again and got the same error :(

Comment: try to follow this giude http://answerleaks.com/question/it/2170697/bundler-isnt-loading-gems

Answer (score -1):

You do seem to have permissions issues with your gems directory. Try resolving that with:

```
sudo find /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ -type d -exec chmod 755 '{}' +
```

Comment: i did this but I still get the same error. "Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle"