# Getting the warning "Insecure world writable dir /home/chance " in PATH, mode 040777 for rails and gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, rvm

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir) but it didn't work and seemed to be for osx. I have a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 install with rvm, rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2. I have a fresh rails app but using either gem or rails results in the following warnings (with lag).

$  ***rails -v***

```
/home/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/chance in PATH, mode 040777
/home/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/chance in PATH, mode 040777
Rails 3.0.5
```

---

$ ***gem -v***

```
/home/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/chance in PATH, mode 040777
1.6.2
```

Just incase it matters, here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem "haml"
gem "formtastic"
gem "will_paginate"
gem "devise"
gem "delayed_job"
gem "whenever"
gem "memcache-client"
gem "capistrano"
group :testing do
  gem "rspec"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "autotest-standalone"
  gem "autotest-rails"
  gem "autotest-growl"
  gem "mocha"
  gem "shoulda"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end

group :development do
  gem "cheat"
  gem "bullet"
  gem "ruby-growl"

end
```

Comment: I also have a bounty on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360327/installed-ruby-on-rails-but-when-i-try-to-run-rails-sever-it-doenst-load-webrick if its the same solution. My server will actually start so I didn't know if it was the same problem. (Im a *nix newb)

Comment: When you said you tried the answer from the other question, did you just use the command suggested there: `sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin`? If so try `chmod go-w /home/chance` instead.

Comment: matt, can you actually answer with that? it was a stupid question but /usr/local/bin failed silently so i thought the chmod went through. Thanks man.

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning Insecure world writable dir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952243/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir)

Comment: Im getting the above error for /usr/lib - And can't even perform chmod go-w as no permission for Any user other than Root. For certain reasons, I can't enter Root. Hence what's the solution now other than ignoring?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

If you tried `sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin` from the other answer, try:

```
chmod go-w /home/chance
```

instead.

What seems to have happened is that somehow your home directory (`/home/chance`) has been added to your `$PATH` (the list of directories the OS searches when trying to find an executable to launch) and has also had its permissions changed so that anyone can write to it. This is potential a security problem, as another user could put an executable into this directory which you could accidentally launch. Ruby notices this and issues the warning.

This command changes the permissions of the directory so that it is no longer world writable.

In unix, file permissions are specified for three categories, the file owner (user), the group of the file (group), and everyone else (other). (See Google for more on unix file permissions).

So breaking down the command above:

`chmod` - change the 'mode' of the file (i.e. its permissions)

`go` - for group(g) and others(o)

`-w` - (minus w) remove write permission

`/home/chance` - the file (or directory) in question

In the other answer the directory that was causing the problem was `/usr/local/bin`, which is owned by root so `sudo` is required to change permissions on it. `/home/chance` is your home directory which is owned by the `chance` user who can change permissions on it - no `sudo` required.

Comment: On my `Lubuntu 16.04` having the warning: `Insecure world writable dir /tmp/. in PATH, mode 041777` was also causing an infinite looping on the warning. I then executed the `sudo chmod go-w /tmp` command and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 40):

You use the **chmod go-w** to whatever path the terminal gives you.

So if it says /usr/local as the path in the error message:

```
warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

You write

```
chmod go-w /usr/local
```

Answer (score 23):

I had to use -R to fix mine:

```
chmod -R go-w /Users/username
```

Comment: Do not run with sudo unless you know what you are doing! (you have checked permissions of every folder within)

Answer (score 9):

(If you are in a Mac) Try the option "Repair Disk Permissions" from the disk utility

[image]

Probably a couple of lines in the details log will say:

```
Permissions differ on “usr”; should be drwxr-xr-x ; they are drwxrwxrwx.
Repaired “usr”
```

Comment: The question is tagged Linux, not Mac. However this thread was the first Google hit, and I'm on a Mac, so this worked for me! [Canonical Mac answer to the same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23271756/62269).

Answer (score 5):

I'm in a Mac, so **/home/*username*** did not work for me. However, when I tried to changing permissions for **/User/*username***, the error persisted.

The thing that got it working was `chmod go-w /User/username/.rvm`

Comment: that's because the problem comes from the /usr folder, not from the /User/username or ~ ( home ) folder.

Answer (score 3):

If your environment does not allow you to fix this error properly (i.e. ruby lives on a network share or some such), see [this answer for a way to suppress the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868701/830254).