# getting error while installing ruby on rails at debian 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, debian, rvm

i successfully installed rvm and ruby 1.9.2 at my debian lenny machine

```
   rvm -v
   rvm 1.8.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

   ruby -v
   ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

now i wanted to install rails

```
    rvm install rails
```

i got some errors and can't solve these problems

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    /home/mrie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:48: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home in PATH, mode 040777
```

i already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380671/getting-the-warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-home-chance-in-path-mode-040)
why and where stands /home in $PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `$PATH` (well, as far as I know :p). It means that your home directory (`/home`, in this case) has too many permissions. As far as I can see, it's set to `777`, which means that just anybody can read, write and execute files in your home directory, which obviously is unsafe.

You should change your directory's rights as following:

```
chmod 755 /home
```

Do not use the `-R` flag (which stands for `recursive`). Files should only have `644`, not `755`.

Comment: ll have a try, thougt my home-folder hasnt write permissions for all users

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you don't use rvm to install rails with.

You do something like: rvm install 1.9.2 && rvm --create use 1.9.2@foo && gem install rails

Comment: thanks for that. its little bit confusing at the beginning ,)