# Error when starting rails server: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I'm following the Ruby tutorial on Treehouse and I keep getting the following error when starting the rails server:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
```

I tried fixing it with the 
    sudo chmod o-w /usr/local/ 
fix and other variations, but sadly that didn't do anything for me.

Even with that error though the server would still start and everything would work fine but now I get a lot of other errors as well and the server won't even start anymore, and I thought they might be connected somehow?

This is the error I get now:

```
 Yass-Bents-MacBook-Pro:treebook yassine$ rails s
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load': /Users/yassine/treebook/app/models/user.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:588:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise.rb:272:in `get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise.rb:306:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise.rb:306:in `add_mapping'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/yassine/treebook/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
    from /Users/yassine/treebook/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/yassine/treebook/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/yassine/treebook/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/yassine/treebook/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/yassine/treebook/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
Yass-Bents-MacBook-Pro:treebook yassine$
```

Any suggestions on fixing this? I tried reinstalling Rails but that didn't help, still the same errors.

Thanks!

Comment: How does your app/models/user.rb look?

Comment: you have an unexpected keyword end, so check the syntax of your model files with `ruby -c app/models/FILENAME.rb`

Answer (score 133):

Try the option "Repair Disk Permissions" from the disk utility

**[EDIT]**

For OS X El Capitan:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /
```

[image]

Comment: YOU NEED MORE UPVOTES!

Comment: Thank you, this fixed a similar problem with a ruby gem installed after updating to OS X 10.9.3.

Comment: After installing the 10.9.3 update on OS X this problem surfaced and I was able to fix it using the "Repair Disk Permissions" from the disk utility. Thanks!

Comment: @Wazery thank you sir I've visited 4 topics and this fixed my problem. I've upvoted you and will post your answer onto the other topics.

Comment: Anyone know why this happens after upgrading to Mavericks etc?

Comment: Nice :) Something so simple trought a GUI. I was searching around in CLI getting crazy (couldn't find any world writeable).

Comment: Such a great feature, fixed all of the permissions on the whole drive. @Wazery thanks!

Comment: saved me a lot of time, have my upvote!

Comment: Wher can i find this?

Comment: you don't know how much i searched for similar problem associated with another SDK, hats off to you man

Comment: for OS X EI Capitan : "sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /"

Comment: On Mojave, Disk Utility => First Aid worked for me

Answer (score 39):

Try your chmod with a `-R` (for recursive):

```
chmod -R o-w /usr/local/
```

Comment: Thanks man, the chmod commands didn't work for me, but I did a repair of the disk permissions in Disk Utility and that fixed it.

Comment: Repairing the disk utils worked for me too. Thanks. :)

Comment: @CorySimmons: mind highlighting your OSX version? (In my case (Snow Leopard or Lion, can't recollect when it happened, that hadn't worked when I ran into the error.)

Comment: I tried the Disk Util method, that dint work. Then I tried what @Denis has mentioned here. That solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

About the **warnings**:

```
... warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
... warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
```

They are telling you that the directory `/usr` (and not `/usr/local`) is world writable. To fix: `chmod -R go-w /usr`.

The **error** says:

```
... `load': /Users/yassine/treebook/app/models/user.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

There's an extra `end` keyword on line 12 in your `user.rb` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can start the server now, the chmod commands didn't work for me, but I did a repair of the disk permissions in Disk Utility and that fixed it.

I had an extra comma in the user.rb files that caused the other errors.

Comment: what's "go" in "chmod -R go-w /usr."?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp `go` means group and others, see `man 1 chmod` for more details.