# Cloned app from Github, get error when trying to start server Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I cloned an app from github and ran bundle install and rake db:migrate just fine. But when I run rails s or rails server to start the server, I get:

```
    Lisa:try_rails_presentation admin-lisa$ rails s
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

Things I have tried:

I updated my disk permissions.

Also, I tried running

```
chmod o-w /usr
```

and

```
chmod 0755 /usr/local
```

and

```
chmod go-w /usr/local/bin
```

and

```
chmod -R o-w /usr/local/bin
```

and

```
sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin
```

No luck so far. Any suggestions? I'm on rails 4 and the app also uses rails 4.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you sure `chmod 755 -R /usr/local` doesn't work for you? Please try it again (without a trailing 0 in the numbers).

Comment: You might read [this question and the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5380671/562459), too. There are several similar questions in the sidebar.

Comment: I ran chmod 755 -R /usr/local again. Still no luck. I also made sure I am the superuser. I'll keep looking at the other similar questions and see if I can find something. Thank you.

Comment: Finally... this one worked, for future reference of anyone who finds this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557507/rails-mysql-on-osx-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib