# Routes missing after terminal restart. Rails 5.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-10, ruby-on-rails-5

I was trying to found an answer for a couple of days  but found nothing. I know there are a lot of similar questions but they can't help me.

I've started learning Rails using http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and was moving forward till terminal restart. Here is an error messages and code samples:

```
walker@DESKTOP-L15NDIS:~/blog$ rails routes
/home/walker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40:
warning: Insecure world writable dir
/home/walker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin in PATH, mode 040777
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

   * development - set it to false
   * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
   * production - set it to true

 You don't have any routes defined!

 Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.

 For more information about routes, see the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.
```

**routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'welcome#index'
    resources :articles
end
```

**config/environments/development.rb**:

```
 config.eager_load = false
```

**config/environments/test.rb**:

```
config.eager_load = false
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.eager_load = true
```

Starting server:

```
 walker@DESKTOP-L15NDIS:~/blog$ rails s
 /home/walker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40:
 warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/walker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin in PATH, mode 040777
 => Booting Puma
 => Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
 => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
 config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

   * development - set it to false
   * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
   * production - set it to true

 Puma starting in single mode...
 * Version 3.7.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
 * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
 * Environment: development
 * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
 Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Localhost displaying error message:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>
> You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

Console output:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-01 16:59:46 +0200 Started GET
"/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-01 16:59:46 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):

actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:226:in `call'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

What you will suggest to fix this?

***Note:*** All this stuff worked well till terminal restart.

P.S. I created another app, and it works fine till terminal restart.

P.P.S. I'm running Linux subsystem on Windows 10 Pro.

P.P.P.S. I can't use any Linux distro or buy MacBook

Comment: Based on the first part, how are your file permissions for routes.rb ?

Comment: @Icguida nice question! I run ls -la but there is no routes.rb in console output. Btw, I can find routes.rb via Sublime or Explorer. File permissions to config folder are 0777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lcguida for question, which made me wonder about another way to find solution.

I finally found the cause to this problem. If someone got stuck by such issue check this
[link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/87#issuecomment-214567251) and also [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems like system has problem with access rights to your home folder.

Try to run `sudo chmod go-w /home/walker` and if issue arises on other paths do the same thing.

Check similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5395932/7445229). In case you want to try Rails without 'infrastructural' problems, check out https://www.railstutorial.org/ and their option with *cloud9* environment.

Comment: I've already tried all methods with changing permissions to the /home folder earlier, this issue persists. Btw, this is _warning_ message because Windows system has access to this folder. And it is insecure but not critical, I guess.