# Chromedriver, --headless Chrome not working WLS Ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver, watir, google-chrome-headless

I'm struggling with running chrome on my WLS, My script is in Ruby using the Watir gem and it works fine when i run it on windows. I have moved my rails project on to WLS as the site will be going live on a virtual machine. I have chromedriver installed and followed guides to install --headless chrome. Can anyone tell me they have a solution to my problem please?

The error I'm having is this:

> /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:154:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
>
> scraper.rb: end of file reached (EOFError)
>
> /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in
>   \rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)`
>
> from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:154:in
>   \readuntil'`
>
> from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:164:in
>   \readline'`
>
> from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in
>   \read_status_line'`
>
> from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in
>   \read_new'`
>
> from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1423:in
>   \block in transport_request'`
>
> from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1420:in
>   \catch'`
>
> from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1420:in
>   \transport_request'`
>
> from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1393:in
>   \request'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:129:in
>   \response_for'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in \request'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:64:in
>   \call'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in
>   \execute'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:102:in
>   \create_session'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:56:in
>   \handshake'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:43:in
>   \initialize'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:46:in
>   \new'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:46:in
>   \for'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in \for'`
>
> from
>   /home/owlmailer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/browser.rb:46:in
>   \initialize'`
>
> from scraper.rb:9:in \new'`
>
> from scraper.rb:9:in \browserAutomation'`
>
> from scraper.rb:26:in \`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. Sounds like a permission issue similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380671/getting-the-warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-home-chance-in-path-mode-04

Comment: pls share some part of code present in scraper.rb which is throwing error.