# Suppress warning "Insecure world writable dir /some/dir/"

Tags: ruby

I've added the current directory to my $PATH (`PATH="$PATH":.`) to make it easier to run shell scripts in the current folder.

Now I often see the following output before a shell command is executed:

```sh
❯ cd Sites/project-a

❯ colorls

# /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin20/rbconfig.rb:229:
# warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/philipp/Sites/project-a in PATH, mode 040777
#
# ... output of the colorls command ...
```

(`colorls` is a ruby gem that I use instead of `ls`, but I also use other gems in many scripts)

I am aware of the meaning and the reason behind it, but I do not want a ruby script to dictate how I should configure my local system.

**Is there a way to suppress the warning without changing the directory permissions?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erroneous "Insecure world writable dir foo in PATH" when running ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708806/erroneous-insecure-world-writable-dir-foo-in-path-when-running-ruby-script) (However, you should probably fix the pretty major security issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to globally disable the "Insecure world writable dir" warning.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868701/313501) suggests replacing the ruby executable with a shell script or to recompile ruby with different options. Both options are difficult and could lead to other unexpected problems, in my opinion.

However, I found a way to disable the warning for individual scripts/gems:

In my case, I use the gem `colorls` to generate a nicer `ls` output. So far, this gem is the only one the frequently triggers the warning. I solved it, by adding the following alias to my `.zshrc` file (or `.bash_profile`)

#### Solution 1

```sh
# Inside .zshrc

alias colorls='colorls --color=always 2>/dev/null'
```

The important part is the error redirection `2>/dev/null`.

**Good:** This alias allows me to add custom parameters to the command, like `colorls --report`

**Bad:** This alias will mask *any error or warning* that the command produces. I want to specifically remove the "Insecure world writable dir" warning.

#### Solution 2

```sh
# Inside .zshrc

alias colorls='colorls --color=always 2>&1 | grep "warning: Insecure world writable dir" -v'
```

**Good:** Instead of redirecting all errors to `/dev/null`, my second attempt redirects all output to `grep`, which strips out the individual warning message.

**Bad:** That solution does not recognize any `colorls` parameters; any parameter will be passed to `grep` instead of `colorls`...

#### Solution 3 (best)

```sh
# Inside .zshrc

colorls() {
    /usr/bin/colorls --color=always $@ 2>&1 | grep "warning: Insecure world writable dir" -v
}
```

This is the best solution: We replace the `colorls` binary with a shell function. That shell function calls the binary. The `$@` variable passes all parameters to the binary, while `grep` removes the specific warning from the output.