# how to install gems without sudo

Tags: ruby, rubygems

On all my gem installs I have to do sudo ? So

> sudo gem install rails

will work, while only

> gem install rails

will not work. How do I remedy it ?

I have rvm installed -

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ which rvm
/home/murtaza/.rvm/bin/rvm

murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ which gem
/home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem
```

However I am also getting this warning when I do any operations with gem -

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ gem
/home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777
```

**EDIT**

I have reinstalled rvm using `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto` (without sudo).

However still when I try installing gem it gives me the following error -

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ gem install rails
/home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /home/murtaza/.gem/specs
```

**EDIT**

I did chown on the whole thing but still getting the error -

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ sudo chown murtaza.murtaza -R ~/.rvm/*


 murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ gem install rails
    /home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
        Permission denied - /home/murtaza/.gem/specs
```

Comment: please, dont install gems with sudo, USE RVM !!! or any other ruby version mannager

Comment: For the warning, let's see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796421/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-when-i-run-a-ruby-or-gem-command) will help.

Comment: Your `chown` looks odd to me. Shouldn't it be `murtaza:murtaza`?

Comment: Done but still the error. However I checked the ~/.gem dir, and it doesnt have a specs file in the first place. What should I do ?

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. I never had this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['sudo gem install' or 'gem install' and gem locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations)

Comment: chmod not chown. It's telling you that you have a world writable directory. Chown is the change the USER. 'chmod 755 /some/directory' will silence it.

Comment: The [answer by @leo.tan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55273128/2632107) is just about perfect for not requiring elevated permissions, though if ya wanted an example where `sudo` could get involved check a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107) for setting up shared Jekyll servers... also that **`Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777`** error is __bad__ and I'm pretty sure you've got something else messed-up on your system now.

Answer (score 31):

Use `chown` on the whole `.rvm` and `.gem` directories back to your user. You probably used `sudo` before and it screwed up permissions.

```
sudo chown -R username:group ~/.rvm
sudo chown -R username:group ~/.gem
```

Of course, change username to *your username* and group to *your group*

Comment: Sorry, `chown` your `~/.gem`.

Comment: I resolved a similar issue using this suggestion, and with the -R recursive flag.

Comment: how do I know what to put for "group" ?

Comment: do an `ls -l` on any directory in your home folder (even the home folder itself) and you'll probably find out.

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm using rvm and 2.1.0 as default. I think I installed a gem using sudo and now I can't install gems without using sudo. Very frustrating because I had my system working pretty good until I did that sudo install. Any ideas?

Comment: @pixel67, I am having the same problem, did you ever get your situation figured out? If so, any suggestions?

Comment: On a worst case scenario, remove rvm and reinstall it.

Comment: @jackerman09 I believe I just reloaded rvm, I'm sorry but it's been a while since I had to deal with this.

Comment: You can also run `sudo rvm fix-permissions username:groupname`

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 20):

When you install them without sudo, Ruby doesn't know where they get installed to. I can't remember where it installs them by default, probably somewhere like ~/.gems or something. Anyway, you can tell Ruby that's where they're installed by setting the GEM_HOME environment variable.

```
$ # assuming your gems are stored in ~/.gems
$ GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gems" ruby my_program.rb
```

If that works, then you might put it in your ~/.bashrc (there are a number of possible files this could go in, depending on your system)

Comment: Going to leave this answer because it might be helpful for someone else, but since you edited it to say you're using rvm, it doesn't make sense any more (rvm will manage this variable for you).

Comment: `GEM_HOME` is also the way if you don't want to use `rvm` when you use system installed Ruby in ephemeral machines e.g. in Docker container.

Answer (score 17):

For Mac users, this works for me...

1. Add GEM_HOME to your `.bash_profile`

For example, `nano ~/.bash_profile` and add `export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem` where the path is to your own Home folder

2. Add the gem executables to your system path

Also in `.bash_profile`, add `export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"`

Source: http://michaelehead.com/2016/02/06/installing-gems-without-sudo.html

Comment: Works in combination with `gem install package --install-dir $GEM_HOME` as mentioned by @Hola Soy Edu Feliz Navidad

Comment: And when getting "can't find gem ... - Gem::GemNotFoundException" set the GEM_PATH in .bash_profile as well: `export GEM_PATH="$GEM_HOME:$GEM_PATH"`

Comment: Works for me (ubuntu)

Answer (score 7):

You should install [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io/). It stores installed rubies and gems in your home dir, so now you don't have to use `sudo` to install gems. It has a lot more features besides this. :)

Comment: Then probably you have installed system-wide RVM. You should reinstall it as a user install.

Comment: See my edit, the rvm path shows under my home folder. Is it still system wide ?

Comment: There are 3 installation modes at https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ Which one did you take?

Comment: That's the problem, you should not have used `sudo` there :)

Comment: @murtaza52: I'd remove RVM and reinstall properly.

Comment: Did you remove RVM before installation?

Comment: I mean I deleted the dir at ~/.rvm . I hope that was enough ?

Comment: @murtaza52: Yeah, that should be enough. But maybe you have something left in your env files. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950260/howto-uninstall-rvm). What are permissions for `~/.rvm` and `~/.rvm/.gem/specs`?

Comment: murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ ls -al ~/ | grep rvm
drwxrwxr-x 24 murtaza murtaza     4096 2012-07-25 12:03 .rvm
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ ls -al ~/.rvm/gem/ | grep specs
ls: cannot access /home/murtaza/.rvm/gem/: No such file or directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14384/discussion-between-murtaza52-and-sergio-tulentsev)

Comment: It was actually `~/.gem/specs`. I mistyped :)

Comment: The gem dir doesnt have a specs file, it only has a ruby dir.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my issue in the following way: (I have ubuntu 17.10)

Open terminal and type:

```
echo "gem: --user-install" >> ~/.gemrc
```

Then add ruby's bin path in .bashrc file

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.gem/ruby/x.x.x/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

MacOS

```
brew install ruby
```

edit   `~/.zshrc`  for  zsh (for Bash could be something like *`~/.bash_aliases`*)

```
# By default, binaries installed by gem will be placed into:
# /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
export GEM_HOME="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/"
export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

try `gem install package --install-dir $HOME/.gem`.

Don't forget setting the path as it was mentioned before `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.gem/bin"`.

Something you have to consider is changing the PATH order like `export PATH="$HOME/.gem/bin:$PATH"`. It might happen for example if you are trying to install rails into your local directory on a OS X system but there is an executable alredy built in. In this case if you don't change the path order you will also receive the following output:

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
>
> $ sudo gem install rails
>
> You can then rerun your "rails" command.

And setting the variable `GEM_HOME` like `export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gems"`