# Still can't install jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Can anyone help with getting this fixed?
Any help would be appreciated!
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/antonioortiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ffi.gemspec
antonios-Mac-Pro:newaortiz.dev antonioortiz$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Really frustrated, can't install jekyll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976724/really-frustrated-cant-install-jekyll)

Comment: It is...Still frustrated!

Comment: This is your fourth question on this topic in three hours. We will help, but it's difficult when you seem incapable of even the simplest troubleshooting. You're likely to get a question ban soon.

Comment: Mike, I have tried, really, but look back and you'll see the way folks have answered really is what is resulting in the frustration. One word answers and not explaining suggestions are no better...

Comment: Please do __not__ use _`sudo gem install someThing`_ (not even out of anger), as others may suggest. Instead consider utilizing `GEM_HOME` and `PATH` variables as shown in a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107) for installing Gems to a user writable path... Which is what your error is telling you in it's own obtuse way with a _`..."Permission denied"...`_ error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use`sudo *your command*` with whatever command you were running and that will handle the error you're having.

More importantly,

Take a moment to read over some of the things that were mentioned to you in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976724/really-frustrated-cant-install-jekyll). It'll help you more than it will hurt you.