# Not able to install jekyll without root access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I am trying to install jekyll, for which there documentation says to install by :

```
gem install jekyll
```

When I try the above it gives an error:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

But when I tried:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

It worked fine and gave following output :

> Successfully installed jekyll-2.5.3
>
> 1 gem installed

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531914/installing-jekyll-without-root) but it is about write permission, while the problem I am facing is about not being able to access a source.

My internet connection is fine and https_proxy is unset as I am not behind any proxy server.
What is the sudo/root access doing that it is able to access it when normally you can't?

Comment: What is it with the _sirens' call_ that sudo has?... If ya re-check that linked to question for a recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107) it'll show that setting the `GEM_HOME` environment variable, among other things, will allow for non-root installation of Gems; it be a good idea to uninstall those that where installed with root level permissions.