# How to Install Jekyll in linux?

Tags: rubygems, installation, jekyll

Im trying to install Jekyll in my linux mint.

```
burrito@linux17 ~ $ sudo gem install jekyll
```

But I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

I have this suplementary packages installed:

```
burrito@linux17 ~ $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
burrito@linux17 ~ $ gem -v
1.8.23
```

Comment: Once you've sorted-out your system's Ruby version it may be a good idea to checkout a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107) that'll show how to use the `GEM_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables such that there's no need to _`sudo gem install someThing`_ for nearly all cases, instead one should look for ways to _`gem install someThing`_ __without__ getting `sudo` involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.x is to old for Jekyll. You need at least ruby 2.0.x.

I advice you to go with [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) in order to manage your ruby versions.

Comment: With rbenv i can have more than one active ruby version in my linux right?

Comment: How can i update Ruby 1.9.x to lastest version in linux?

Comment: rbenv is the simplest way. You can work with 2.2 globally and chose to work with 2.3 on a specific project. If you just want to update your ruby version up, I encourage you to search, I guess, http://askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ruby installed yet? If not,

```
gem install ruby
```

afterwards you should have no problems installing jekyll, if you do try the following:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin/ jekyll
```

check to see if jekyll was installed by checking the version

```
jekyll -v
```

if you get an error about the bundler, install it using:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin/ bundler
```

Should be fine after.