# Can't Install Jekyll

Tags: python, ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04, jekyll

I get the error (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo gem install 

jekyllBuilding native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/ffi-1.9.14/gem_make.out
```

Common solutions like installing ruby-dev are not working.

Please help.Thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove ruby`
    `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev`
    `gem install jekyll`

Comment: Use https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: @DavidJacquel thanks. plz give a few steps on what to do wrt the problem. i will accept the answer. thanks.

Comment: Might be worth the time to check a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107) that'll show some methods of setting-up a user account for non-`sudo` installed Gems... aside from account setup `sudo` isn't required when using _`gem install someThing`_ via one of the _proper_ ways.