# Jekyll - Issue when trying to run gem install jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm quite new to the command line and unfamiliar with where the root of the issue is but when I try and run `gem install jekyll`, I get the below:

```
$ gem install jekyll
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Can someone explain the resolution and the origin of the issue. I understand it's a permission error but I don't understand why I get this. If someone could explain it, that'd be awesome :) thank you.

Comment: Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107) I posted elsewhere on how to install Jekyll to a user writable location via modifications to the `GEM_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables... it's something I forget to do almost every-time I have a server to set-up, thus there be a project linked within that answer that at least serves my wants... There is __no__ reason to do _`sudo gem install someThing`_ as so many others will suggest, or try, as it's just a matter of setting a few environment variables and getting'em `source`d properly.

Answer (score 1):

As Mac user the below was straight forward

```
❯ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
❯ brew install ruby
```

##### Option (1) adding the path if you are using zhs

```
❯ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
❯ source ~/.zshrc
```

##### Option (2) adding the path if you are using bash

```
❯ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
❯ source ~/.bash_profile
```

You will need to reopen the terminal

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 revision a528908271) [x86_64-darwin21]
$ gem install jekyll bundler 
$ bundle install
```

If all ran as expected you should be able to run jekyll server

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
```

> Note:
> When running the last command you may face the error `taint_check': undefined method` tainted?
> If so you may need to update the liquid by running : $ bundle update liquid

Comment: Thank you a lot for the note about liquid!

Answer (score 0):

Your Ruby seems to be installed system-wide. In order for `gem install` to install gems on a system level it needs root (superuser) access.

The easiest way to give root access to a single command is to use `sudo`. So to give `gem install` root access you would do:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

Run `man sudo` to get more information about the `sudo` command.

If you would prefer to install Ruby as a user-level binary instead of system-wide, take look at RVM or RBEnv:

http://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/
http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rbenv/