# Can't install Jekyll on Mint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I installed ruby and ruby gems, updated both of them, tried to install jekyll using the command

```
sudo gem install jekyll bundler
```

it gave me this

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161209-4826-wdshax.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.14/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.14/gem_make.out
Successfully installed bundler-1.13.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.13.6
Done installing documentation for bundler after 7 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Here is what it says in the log file:

```
package configuration for libffi is not found
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
In file included from /usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from conftest.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:26:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

I'm running Linux Mint, and I can't find anything to help this problem. One gem of jekyll is installed and I'm able to create jekyll projects, but only partially and I can't run it on my local host and edit it.

Any more questions let me know and I'll try my best to help provide the details.

Comment: **1st)** You shouldn't need to use `sudo` to install gems. Ruby gems are installed in user space. **2nd)** Run `apt-get install build-essential` to install all packages needed to build programs in your Mint box.

Comment: I can't use just simply gem, I need sudo gem install, otherwise it gives me a permissions error.

Comment: This is happening, probably, because you are using the Ruby package your Linux distribution provides. This is not good at all. You should install Ruby in user space using **rvm** or **rbenv**. This is the best procedure.

Comment: This is the link to [RVM](http://rvm.io/).

Comment: I installed it by downloading the tar.gz file from the ruby website: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Comment: If I were you I'd install it using **rvm** (or **rbenv**, but I prefer **rvm**). It is the standard way to install Ruby for Linux and it avoids lots of permission issues and other problems. But this is with you. If you want to waste your time and patience trying other ways, feel free to do so.

Comment: how do I install it using rvm? I uninstalled ruby and ruby gems, then installed rvm, but I can't use the gem command

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: yes, it is extremely confusing

Comment: If you really installed **rvm**, next step is installing Ruby. To install the most recent release, just do `rvm install 2.3.3`. Please, DON'T USE sudo when you do this.

Comment: Please take alook at this:  http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/06/building-native-extensions-for-ruby-gems.html

Comment: The documentation is NOT confusing. You may have a lot of things to read, of course, but they are not confusing at all. And if you don't have any patience to read, then you are possibly in the wrong area. Programming requires a lot of reading.

Comment: Might be worth checking a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107), specifically the `TLDR` portion which shows how to avoid the need for `root` level permissions when installing Jekyll and related Gems and near the end, within the last script example, for ways of _`bundle install someThing`_ also without any _`sudo`ing_ required... in short sudo is not a _salve all_

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint 18. Installing build-essential solved it:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been there. Some linux need custom treatment till get done to do something.
You can try to

```sh
bundle exec jekyll serve --trace
```

If you pass, you will find url like this: http://127.0.0.1:4000/