# What is the proper way to install Jekyll?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, jekyll

I tried installing Jekyll using `gem install jekyll`, but it looks like permissions were denied. I read using `sudo` is not the right way to install gems either. I am new to bash and ruby so I am not sure where to go from here.

```
user@user-pc:~$ gem install jekyll
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems
```

Comment: I am also using windows, FYI

Comment: But does this question belong to SO? I believe you may get better results with [SuperUser](http://SuperUser.com)

Comment: I found a few resources. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/

Comment: Setting the `GEM_HOME` environment variable and pre'ppending something similar to what's shown in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107) to the `PATH` variable is generally all that's required to enable _`gem install someThing`_ to a user directory... not sure about Windows, but it works on _Unix-ish_ systems... what does _`gem install jekyll --install-dir ~/.gem`_ produce?... you're getting that error because your user account doesn't seem to have write permissions at the given path.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install Ruby using **Rbenv** as mentioned [here](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04)

 Installing Ruby using **apt-install ruby** will install an older version,
 which might be the cause for a similar error during jekyll installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, I'd recommend re-installing Ruby using [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) — get the 32-bit download for the latest version (2.3.3 as of this writing).

Then boot up a new terminal and `gem install jekyll` again.