# Can't install jekyll gem at linux (classifier-reborn ruby version error)

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, rvm, jekyll

I'm working on ElementaryOS (linux) and this is what I have:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
rvm list
rvm rubies
   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
which ruby
/home/ofcapl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
```

And when I try to install `jekyll gem` I've got an error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    classifier-reborn requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

I've tried to install it on ruby 2.2.0 and 1.9.3 but with no success.. Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643629/how-to-install-gems-without-sudo)

I've reinstalled rvm and rubygems without sudo and then installed jekyll gem without sudo.