# Controlling Vagrant plugin dependencies via Ansible

Tags: ruby, vagrant, ubuntu-12.04, nokogiri, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that installs Vagrant, and then instructs Vagrant to install a specific plugin. Vagrant has trouble installing a gem it needs, and says:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'` succeeds before bundling.
stdout: Installing the 'vagrant-aws --version '0.5.0'' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
```

While I have trouble installing Nokogiri using the command:

```
$ sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'
```

as vagrant does it, I have found that I *can* install Nokogiri manually, using this command:

```
$ sudo gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.6.2 -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2
```

Even after I installed the gem manually, vagrant still fails if I manually tell it to install the plugin.

Is there a way to get better control of these dependencies so that vagrant won't fail and my playbook will complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was missing some key dependencies: `build-essential`, `libxslt1-dev`, `libxml2-dev`, and `zlib1g-dev`. I found this comment here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/163#issuecomment-27603855 very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an issue with using sudo to install the ruby gem.

I solved this issue by installing Ruby Version Manager, which installs and manages gems in your home directory.

After installing RVM I could install nokogiri without sudo, but vagrant-aws still failed to install until I re-installed vagrant. If you are building a fresh environment with Ansible then you can probably just install RVM before you install vagrant the first time (or any other ruby stuff). There are [other ways to fix your gem permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643629/how-to-install-gems-without-sudo) as well.

Here are the steps I took:

Install Ruby Version Manager (https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Install nokogiri without sudo

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Re-install vagrant (http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads)