# Trying to install ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm tryng to install rails with `gem install rails` but when I try that I get

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.`

So I tried using `sudo gem install rails` and I get

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I've checked on the internet and it says I should install RVM but when I try to do that it tells me :

```
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/manhattan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/zlib:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared', please read /Users/manhattan/.rvm/log/1589107425_ruby-2.7.0/configure.log There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Could someone help me please.

Comment: Hey Harry, seems like you don't have the right permission the folders. Can you take a look at this answer and see if it helps you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11644182/702436

Comment: I'm sorry I just followed the it said we had to put our group. But what exactly is the group you are talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ruby gems (like Rails) on a Mac is a common source of confusion and frustration. Unfortunately, most solutions are incomplete, outdated, and provide bad advice. You should never need to use `sudo` or change permissions.

I wrote an article explaining [why you should never use sudo to install gems](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=61711133).

This write permissions error is very common, and is due to trying to install Rails using the system Ruby (the version of Ruby that came preinstalled on your Mac). Learn [why you shouldn't use the system Ruby to install gems on a Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby-to-install-gems-on-a-mac/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=61711133).

There are many questions on Stack Overflow about this permissions error, and the solution is the same. So, instead of repeating myself, I'll just link to my popular answer (480+ votes) here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873916/928191

Answer (score 0):

you can change the permission of the directory you are working on

```
# chmod -R 777 DIR_NAME
# cd DIR_NAME
# gem install rails
```

Comment: I work in a directory called 'rails' so i just typed chmod -R 777 rails then cd rails then gem install rails and it got me the same error as before. Did I do it wrong ?

Comment: you did this as root or as the normal user

Comment: as a normal user

Comment: try 
# sudo chmod -R 777 /Library/Ruby/Gems
if it works so the problem was that you just need to give your user permissions on this path