# Error while running Ruby on Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, web-services, osx-mavericks

I'm running into this error when I run the rails server. The server runs fine, but I think this could be a security issue and would like to patch it up ASAP, but I can't get to do it even if I change the permission of the directory.

As you can see on my log, the server runs fine but I get a security warning:

```
/Users/SweetMedia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:37: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Volumes/SWEETMEDIA/ruby/myapp/simple_cms in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/SweetMedia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:220: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Volumes/SWEETMEDIA/ruby/myapp/simple_cms in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-03-24 14:27:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-03-24 14:27:57] INFO  ruby 2.1.1 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
[2014-03-24 14:27:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=26930 port=3000
```

How can I get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [warning: Insecure world writable dir when I run a ruby or gem command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796421/warning-insecure-world-writable-dir-when-i-run-a-ruby-or-gem-command)

> Just `sudo chmod go-w /opt/local/bin` at a shell prompt

Or, in your case:

```
sudo chmod go-w /Volumes/SWEETMEDIA/ruby/myapp/simple_cms
```

Comment: I did that and the warning persists.